Clarifying confusion about ranges and images
Please consider a function $f: D \to E$. So this means $D$ is the domain of the function, and $E$ is the range of the function.
However, suppose there exists at least one element $y$ in $E$ for which there is no element $x$ in $D$ such that $f(x) = y$. Meaning, $im(f) \neq E$.
This leads me to two questions:

Can we say that any set $S$ which contains $E$ can also be considered the range of $f$?

If so, I mean, is the choice of range for $f$ somewhat arbitrary? I feel like the concept of an "image" is well defined, however the concept of "range" seems to mean something like "all values which we could theoretically reach from $f$". However, $f$ only ever reaches the elements which are in the image. So what does this mean exactly and what purpose does the concept of a range serve?


